# Add vertical spacing of a long sentence in description

Tags: itemize, enumitem

[image]

---

### code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,amsfonts}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{description}

\item [First] This is a short sentence.

\item [Second] This is a very long sentence and eventually it will go to the second line in this item but the vertical space between the first line and the second line is too small that a fraction $\dfrac{p}{q}$, the top of p almost touches the bottom of the previous line

\item [Third] I want too add vertical space in every line in an item but not the space between items 

\end{description}

\end{document}
```

Comment: you can use `\begin{spacing}{1.5} ... \end{spacing}` with this `\usepackage{setspace}`

Comment: @CroCo Looks like you should turn this into an answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `\begin{spacing}{1.5} ... \end{spacing}` with this `\usepackage{setspace}`

You can also use the `before` key offered by `enumitem` package and set the stretch as in the following code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}    
\usepackage{enumitem,lipsum}           %% lipsum only for demo    
\usepackage{setspace}

\begin{document}
%\begin{spacing}{1.5}
\begin{description}[before=\setstretch{1.5}]  <<--- here

\item [First] This is a short sentence.

\item [Second] This is a very long sentence and eventually it will go to the second line in this item but the vertical space between the first line and the second line is too small that a fraction $\dfrac{p}{q}$, the top of p almost touches the bottom of the previous line

\item [Third] I want too add vertical space in every line in an item but not the space between items

\end{description}
%\end{spacing}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]